# How to use check-all-the-things with a .deb package?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, lintian

I am looking and using a github repo. which has a debian directory and debian/rules file which can be used to build the package/tool into a debian package. Using lintian I was able to get some warnings which upstream would probably fix in sometime.

I heard some cool things about check-all-the-things and while it has more than a handful of dependencies I was able to install it. But while using lintian on a debian package is easy with

$lintian somedebianpackage.deb

check-all-the-things doesn't have any clear instructions. Even the manpage is somewhat confusing. I do understand that some flags are dangerous, but is there a way to run all the tests on a debian package to try some QA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run it in the package source folder:

```
check-all-the-things
```

You'll probably want to `tee` that to a log file, the output is very verbose. The defaults are safe enough...