# how to tell check-all-the-things to give verbose output.

Tags: debian

I am on Debian mate. I am trying to use check-all-the-things on a repo. I got this at the very end in Remarks -

```
Remarks:
- dangerous check: afl bfbtester lockdep perl-b-lint perl-syntax-check zzuf
- help needed: acheck android-lint ansible-lint cbmc checkmp3 chk-origtargz codespell cpants-lint cppclean debian-tracker doc8 erlang-elvis ...
- modifies files: autoscan autoupdate stylish-haskell wrap-and-sort
- no matching files: 7z-test acheck afl android-lint ansible-lint appstream-util-validate appstreamcli-validate autodep8 autoscan autoupdate ...
- no output: bashate bitmap-gnuplot bitmap-inkscape bitmap-povray bitmap-synfig checkbashisms cpuinfo disabled-tests dsa-private-key ...
- no specific checks: *.data *.ogg *.png *.py *.pyc *.txt GPL3 LICENCE LICENSE arguments
- trimmed: bitmap-gimp fdupes fhs http licensecheck pep8 pyflakes pyflakes3 pylint pylint3 spellintian suspicious-source todo
```

I looked up at the manpage of check-all-the-things but didn't see anything. I'm looking for a way to let it be as verbose as possible without using the dangerous checks. I had already asked about check-all-the-things earlier, see [How to use check-all-the-things with a .deb package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310148/how-to-use-check-all-the-things-with-a-deb-package)

Answer (score 0):

To view all the logs, run the following:

```
check-all-the-things --silent-checks show --remarks-lines -1 --checks-output-lines -1
```

This displays checks which don't output anything, and doesn't cut output after a given number of lines (1 by default for `--remarks-lines`, 10 by default for `--checks-output-lines`).

If you want to enable checks which modify files, add `--flags +modify`; these are checks which aren't considered dangerous. You can verify what `check-all-the-things` is going to do before letting it loose by adding `--commands show`.

All this is in the manpage...